# EJS pages with parameters and partials hang

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a weird problem happening on my ejs pages.  When I include header and footer partials on any page that loads with a route parameter, the page hangs.  When I hit the stop button on the page load, the page loads fine.  On pages that do not have a route parameter, I have no issues.

I get the following error in node (the page loads with a route parameter called eventid):

```
    params for results to find by eventid:  { eventid: 'app.css' }
    SOMETHING WENT WRONG GETTING RESULT:  { CastError: Cast to ObjectId 
failed for value "app.css" at path "event_id" for model "results"
```

I added a comment below after posting this question.  I figure I would add some information here to give more details.  My app.css link in the header partial is the cause of my problems.  When I comment it out it works fine.  In node, I've used the following line to include files in my resources folder which is in the root of my app.  This works fine except when i load it using the partials footer.  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'resources')))`

Sample pages...

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<h3>Sample page</h3>

<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Header partial...

```
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="google.com"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i> PESers Only</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/events">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/results">Link 2</a></li> 
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- <div id="wrapper"> -->
            <div class="container">
```

Footer Partial...

```
           </div> <!-- close container -->
        <!-- </div> close wrapper -->
    </body>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-content list-inline">  
                 Footer text | Contact Us
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: So it turns out that the problem is with my app.css declaration in my header partial. When I comment it out I don't have any hangs on pages with a route parameter. In node, on pages with route parameters, my parameter is being assigned app.css { eventid: 'app.css' }.  Why is this happening and how can I have my app.css page be properly included?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem I was having was related to the referencing of external files (in this case my app.css file).  I was referencing it in my ejs header partial using: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">` however the error was fixed when I added a backslash to the href: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app.css">`.

Essentially, when referencing resources such as a css file that is in a folder that is declared in app.use (`app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/resources"));`) you need the backslash to reference the root of your application and then access the resource you plan to reference in the ejs views.